# Seeing only default list of KML attributes in QGIS attribute table?

Tags: qgis, kml

I converted a shapefile to kml using `ogr2ogr`. Glancing at the output, it looks correct -- it has a `<Schema ...>` and each `<ExtendedData>` references the schema ([I uploaded a snippet here](https://gist.github.com/hampelm/5099858)).

However, when I open the kml in QGIS and select "View attribute table", I only see a default list of attributes (Name, description, timestamp, begin...). Is this a limitation of the KML reader, or an error in the file?